# Accessing Global variable across files

Tags: c++, arrays, static, global-variables

I need to access `m[]` in `c.cpp` from `d.cpp`. The array `m[]` is a member of `CD` within a namespace and is declared in `c.h` within that class. So I declare a static array `s[]` in the same class `CD` in the file `c.h`. Instantiate it in c.cpp and use a function to copy the elements of the original array `m[]` to static array`s[]`. Then, I `#include "c.h"` in `d.cpp` where I need to access it.

c.h

```
namespace k{
class CD {
string m[10];
static string s[10];
}}
```

c.cpp

```
#include "c.h"
namespace k{
string CD::s[10] = {"q"}
}
```

d.cpp

```
#include "c.h"
void func(){
string n = k::CD::s[0];    
}
```

But I am getting an error saying undefined reference to `k::CD::s`.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: With the code you show, you should be getting plenty more errors. Please learn how to create a [mre]. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Oh and please also tell us how you *build* the program. If you do it in a terminal show us the exact commands you use. If you use an IDE tell us how you set up the project, and what files are listed as being part of the project. And if there's any text build output then copy-paste it into the question.

Comment: `#include c.h` => `#include "c.h"`

Comment: "_So I declare a static array `s[]` in the same class `CD` in the file `c.h`_" - You make it sound like you did that to get access to `m` - but the single instance `s` and all the `m`:s aren't connected. If my answer doesn't solve your problems, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

c.h

```
#ifndef C_H_HEADER_GUARD // add header guard
#define C_H_HEADER_GUARD

#include <string> // you need this header

namespace k {

class CD {
    // string is in the "std" namespace, so:
    std::string m[10];      // note that this is private!

// "s" can't be private since you want to access it outside the class, in `func()`:
public:
    static std::string s[10];
}; // class definitions need to end with ;

} // namespace k

#endif
```

c.cpp

```
#include "c.h" // enclose the header with quotation marks

namespace k {
using namespace std;      // in here it's ok to use namespace std:
string CD::s[10] = {"q"}; // missing ;
} // namespace k
```

d.cpp

```
#include "c.h" // again, quotation marks

void func() {
    std::string n = k::CD::s[0]; // missing std::
}
```

Now, this will compile the two translation units into `c.o` and `d.o` that you can use when linking with the TU containing `main` later.

```
g++ -c c.cpp d.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors
```

Since `d.cpp` doesn't have a `d.h` declaring the function `func` though, you'll need to declare that where you want to use it. Not nice, but:

```
void func();
```